How can I make photos attached to reminders show up in notifications?
When I create a new reminder in the Reminders app with an image attached, I wanted the image to be shown in the reminder notification like shown below, it currently does not. I can make a shortcut that shows a notification with an image attached, but that doesn't work for the "Add new reminder" shortcut action. Here's a sample shortcut: https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/65d0a673a927450187614064fabb45de



You can use a workaround with the Shortcuts app to get a similar effect.
To do this, just click on details and then choose a photo you like where it says "add image." When the notification pops up, the picture should appear with it.

Which shortcut action is it? Because I said in the post that I can't attach an image in the "Add new reminder" action / block.
